# jQuery refresh of buttons that are multiple levels below accordion-set parent

Tags: jquery-mobile, button, nested, refresh, accordion

I have multiple accordion-set's nested in side of each other, they make a types of multi-category sorted list. Anywhere from 3 to 5 steps into the accordion nests I can start having actual items (buttons), they are in reality stylized 'A' elements.

I'm able to get the nested accordion-sets to refresh on successful AJAX return, but can not seem to figure out how to get the buttons to refresh and take on the jQ mobile styling.

$('#main-market-list').find('div[data-role="collapsible-set"]').collapsibleset({refresh:true}); is what Im using for the accordion-sets, whats the button version of the same logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try `$(".ui-page-active").trigger("create")` to force JQM to restyle the entire page.So your buttons too will get styled along with accordion sets.

edit: you could try `$('.button-class').button('refresh');` where button-class is the class name for the links which you would like to style.

Comment: +1 for a working solutions, -1 for overkill. I'll accept your answer if nothing better comes up; guess it'll be on of those things that I circle back to after a couple iterations.

But would really like something a little more specific to refreshing the buttons only.